# Pick value in a group from multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

my data has the following structure. For each country and id, from the the shipment column (china and hk),
if a group has both china and hk, The new column shipment should have HK
if a group has china , The new column shipment should have China
if a group has HK , The new column shipment should have HK
if NA, it should be NA

Similar for the M, Q, and Y column. depending on which column has the value for a given group, it should go under single column period.

I have included my attempt below. But wondering if there is a better way to do this. Instead of true or false, how do I include `shipment_hk` or `shipment_china`. So that it is readable to user. Also, the quarterly value does not seem work in the ifelse condition.

```r
library(dplyr)
sample_df %>% tibble::as.tibble() %>% 
dplyr::group_by(country,id) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(periods = ifelse(Monthly == "Monthly", "monthly", ifelse(Quarterly == "Quarterly", "quarterly", ifelse(Yearly == "Yearly", "yearly", "")))) %>%
dplyr::mutate(shipment = any(shipment_hk %in% "send to hk")) %>% 
dplyr::select(country,id, type,periods,shipment)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 5
#> # Groups:   country, id [7]
#>    country id     type        periods shipment
#>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>       <chr>   <lgl>   
#>  1 group_1 2.1    ""          <NA>    FALSE   
#>  2 group_1 2.1    "bar"       monthly FALSE   
#>  3 group_1 2.1    "chocolate" monthly FALSE   
#>  4 group_1 2.17   ""          <NA>    FALSE   
#>  5 group_1 2.17   "bar"       monthly FALSE   
#>  6 group_1 2.17   "chocolate" monthly FALSE   
#>  7 group_1 2.2    ""          <NA>    TRUE    
#>  8 group_1 2.2    ""          <NA>    TRUE    
#>  9 group_1 2.2    "bar"       <NA>    TRUE    
#> 10 group_1 2.2    "chocolate" <NA>    TRUE    
#> 11 group_2 1      ""          <NA>    TRUE    
#> 12 group_2 1      ""          <NA>    TRUE    
#> 13 group_2 1      "bar"       monthly TRUE    
#> 14 group_2 2.1    ""          <NA>    FALSE   
#> 15 group_2 2.1    "bar"       monthly FALSE   
#> 16 group_2 2.12.1 ""          <NA>    TRUE    
#> 17 group_2 2.12.1 ""          <NA>    TRUE    
#> 18 group_2 2.12.1 "donut"     <NA>    TRUE    
#> 19 group_2 2.12.2 ""          <NA>    FALSE   
#> 20 group_2 2.12.2 "bar"       <NA>    FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

```
dput(sample_df)
structure(list(country = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
"group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
"group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
"group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_3", "group_3", 
"group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3"), id = c("2.1", "2.1", 
"2.1", "2.17", "2.17", "2.17", "2.2", "2.2", "2.2", "2.2", "1", 
"1", "1", "2.1", "2.1", "2.12.1", "2.12.1", "2.12.1", "2.12.2", 
"2.12.2", "2.17", "2.17", "2.17", "2.18", "2.18", "2.18"), type = c("", 
"bar", "chocolate", "", "bar", "chocolate", "", "", "bar", "chocolate", 
"", "", "bar", "", "bar", "", "", "donut", "", "bar", "tiles", 
"tiles", "tiles", "tiles", "tiles", "tiles"), shipment_china = c("send to china", 
NA, NA, "send to china", NA, NA, "send to china", NA, NA, NA, 
"send to china", NA, NA, "send to china", NA, "send to china", 
NA, NA, "send to china", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), shipment_hk = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "send to hk", NA, NA, NA, "send to hk", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "send to hk", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Monthly = c(NA, "Monthly", "Monthly", NA, "Monthly", "Monthly", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Monthly", NA, "Monthly", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Monthly", NA, NA, NA, NA), Quarterly = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Quarterly", 
NA, "Quarterly", NA, NA, NA, "Quarterly", NA, NA), Yearly = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Yearly", "Yearly", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

Comment: Actually, No. For example to the ID 2.2 we have both china and hk selected. So, HK override the shipment column. For 2.2 in group_1, we have to send bar and chocolate yearly to HK. Even though for that id we have china and HK both selected.

Comment: yes, if any in group is HK then that group shipment goes to HK. The `any` func I used seems to work. But, would like to have the name instead T or F. Also, missing the quarterly in the date period, not sure why the spelling seems to be right.

Comment: actually, this works. I get "send to hk" and NA values. I can replace the NA to shipment_china

Comment: you can put that in the answer and will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using `coalesce` and using `case_when` instead of the nested `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)

sample_df %>%
  group_by(country, id) %>%
  mutate(periods = coalesce(Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly),
         shipment = case_when(
           any(shipment_hk == "send to hk") ~ "send to hk",
           any(shipment_china == "send to china") ~ "send to china",
           TRUE ~ NA_character_
         ))
```

This will prioritize `shipment_hk` over `shipment_china` in your new `shipment` column.

Comment: When this is failing when I have NA values for both column, `shipment_hk` and `shipment_china`

Comment: Just NA would be fine

Comment: updated the data. Yes, it does give NA, but the problem is in the `ifelse(any...)` ..it gives me a column with "shipment_hk"  and "NA" values. instead of "shipment_hk"  and "shipment_china". So, now I don't know if NA is true NA or its "shipment_china"

Comment: Something like case_when would help to identify all the cases. the any is just taking yes or no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224064/discussion-between-user5249203-and-ben).